# ¿Por que mi arreglo tiene mas espacio del que le puse?

Tags: c++, array

Tengo entendido que los arreglos estáticos no permiten su recorrido mas allá del tamaño que se les ha asignado, pero no entiendo porque en el siguiente código mi arreglo permite un recorrido de hasta 2356, siendo que su tamaño es 4, nunca se me presento un problema así o no que yo recuerde, a que se debe esto?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    float M[4][4];
    for(int i = 2100; i < 2300; i++){
    cout << M[i][1] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No es que tu arreglo tenga más espacio, es que ni el compilador ni el entorno de ejecución implementan ningún mecanismo para verificar si te sales del tamaño que tienes reservado. Es tu responsabilidad el no intentar acceder nunca a elementos más allá de los límites. Si lo haces el comportamiento es indefinido. Estarías accediendo a memoria que no es ya parte de tu arreglo, sino otra parte del programa (quizás otra variable), o memoria protegida. En el segundo caso la CPU abortaría la ejecución con un "fallo de segmentación".

Comment: Entiendo, pero antes la consola, que es donde compilo mis programas de c++, me cancelaba la ejecucion mostrando un IndexOutOfRangeException , no es eso lo que normalmente deberia mostrar?

Comment: Bueno amigo, gracias, logre encontrar algo sobre el tema y parece que es normal..., me extraño bastante ya que trabajo con c++ por 3 años, y nunca me habia ocurrido algo asi, en fin, desde hoy usare vectores en lugar de arreglos, al diablo con ellos

Comment: Un _comportamiento indefinido_ es lo que tiene, que es indefinido. Cualquier cosa puede pasar, desde que te de un segmentation fault, o no.

Comment: Como comenta @SuperG280, es indefinido, no esta asegurado nada. Creo que el `IndexOutOfRangeException` que te ha salido es una herramienta que implementa tu entorno de desarollo como ayuda para que pruebes tu codigo. Pero en el buil de produccion no va a incluir eso. Y cuando compiles para otros sistemas menos.